# JPA, pattern or anti-pattern: to have both flat and related sets of mappings?

Tags: jpa

This question concerns using JPA to manage some data where some scenarios benefit from the full object model and others seem to be better implemented by a much flatter model. I'm therefore inclined to create two models. I get the feeling that this is not a good idea but I'm hard-pressed to see exactly why, or what the alternatives may be.

The basis scenario is that there is an Entity, lets call it A which the many side of a relationship with entity B. So in the database A has a foreign key field and if the full object model we see (simplified, getters/setters removed)

```
   public Class A {
        public int aKey;
        public B;
        // more attributes 
   }

   public Class B {
        public int bKey;
        public List<A> collectionOfA;
        // and more
   }
```

One particular scenario is handling the arrival into the system of new As. They come from some external in the form of, say, text files. the insertion code needs to

```
   for each CVS record
         get the bKey from the record
         find the B, or manage any error
         create the A, setting the B
         persist
```

Now in fact my scenario is more complex, there are several such relationships, so that find/set pairing is repeated several times.

Alternatively I could (and in fact have) created a second mapping for the A table

```
  public Class Ainserter {
        public int aKey;
        public int bKey;
        // more attributes 
   }
```

Now I just set the two values and persist. This does assume that the DB will have the referential integrity constraints, but with the tooling I'm using that is the case. In this, and in many legacy systems the DB pre-exists and may be accessed from both the new JPA code and other even non-Java code. I therefore don't see a reason to put the referential integrity checking in the JPA code in such simple cases.

I can see that potentially there are opportunities for aspects of the full model to become stale with respect to my insertions, but in a legacy environment there could be insertions happening in the DB itself at any time. So I don't see a new problem here.

I can also see potential for confusion if the same Entity Context were used for both models, but that can be avoided by suitable encapsulation.

Any other thoughts?

Edit:

There is a suggestion from axtavt to use EntityManager.getReference(B.class, bkey) to get the B instance. My understanding is that if I do this then to be properly conforming with the JPA programming model I am supposed to set both sides of the relationship, hence I would need to visit the "referenced" B object and add my A into his collection.

Edited again:

I was concerned that visiting B would cause a database lookup, so in performance terms I would not  get the win. I have it on very good authority that, at least OpenJPA, will in fact not need to "inflate" B if we only access B's key and the collection of As - and so getReference() is a good suggestion. I seems reasonable that a well designed JPA implementation would have such optimisations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JPA has an `EntityManager.getReference()` method, which basically combines the approaches you describe.

It gets primary key and returns a proxy object with that primary key without hitting the database. So, you can use that object to initialize the relationship field, exactly as you want to do in your second approach.

Comment: Thanks, it's something I had not considered. I'm not sure whether it achieves the reduction in db access, my edit to the question explains my puzzlement.

Comment: Edited question to say why I now am unpuzzled, and hence believe in the getReference() strategy. @axtavt: thanks.